# Create grok timestamp pattern with GMT word

Tags: regex, logstash-grok, grok

I have a logfile with timestamp as follows

```
Tue Oct 24 20:44:51 GMT+02:00 2017
```

We can use below grok pattern for timestamp with timezone

```
%{DATESTAMP_OTHER: timestamp}   // work for "Tue Oct 24 20:44:51 UTC 2017"
```

But it says not matched for GMT format.

What can be the Gork pattern for  "Tue Oct 24 20:44:51 GMT+02:00 2017"?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(?<TIMESTAMP_GMT>%{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} (?<TZ>GMT(?<DIFF>\+[0-9:.]+)|[PMCE][SD]T|UTC) %{YEAR})
```

Here, the main components of the `DATESTAMP_OTHER` pattern are the same, just `TZ` is replaced with `(?<TZ>GMT(?<DIFF>\+[0-9:.]+)|[PMCE][SD]T|UTC)` that matches

- `GMT(?<DIFF>\+[0-9:.]+)` - `GMT` followed with `+` and then 1 or more digits, `.` or/and `.`
- `|` - or
- `[PMCE][SD]T` - `P`, `M`, `C` or `E` followed with `S` or `D` and then `T`
- `|` - or
- `UTC` - `UTC`

The `(?<DIFF>\+[0-9:.]+)` part may be written more precisely, say, as `(?<DIFF>\+\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2}(?:\.\d+)?)?)` or made optional by adding a `?` at the end, it depends on what custom date format you have to handle.